# Can't get ASP.Net to run properly on IIS 7/Windows Server 2008 combo

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I'm trying to deploy a segment of our site to a new server, and I'm getting the following error when I try to pull up any ASP.Net page...

"401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied."

What permissions should I be checking?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What type of authentication is the site using? Windows, Anonymous? Have you installed the appropiate security features? Try checking "Turn Windows feature on or off" - IIS - WWWS - Security...

Comment: The site is using Windows Authentication.  It is an admin site.

Comment: @danielm83 Is Windows Authentication installed and enabled?

Comment: I followed these steps to install the Windows Authentication service, but I still get the error.

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication

Comment: Ah!  Windows Authentication does not show up in IIS as an option to enable yet.  Even though I have installed it.

Comment: Ah again!  I just had to close IIS and start it back up and it was there.  I enabled and that fixed it!  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure then danielm83, I'm assuming that you've made the folder an application or you've added a virtual directory and made it an application. Have you set the appropriate Application pool to Classic .NET AppPool or similar?